# Limit access to page with valid e-mail verification on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im using wordpress for my website and i need to limit the access to all users when they go to a certain page by requesting their email address. This email has to be a valid one of course, I'm searching for an easy extension to add, but can not find one since i do not fully know how to code one.
Can someone please show me a valid extension or an easy enough bit of code.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to allow access only to certain visitors is probably to register them as Subscribers (per https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber) and use a plugin (or call `is_user_logged_in()` inside your theme) to protect the page content from anyone not logged in.

(You can/should disable users from signing up themselves, of course!)

Edit: if you want to *collect* new email addresses before redirecting to a page, you may want to look into something similar to (but not exactly like) https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/.